# Bootstrap modal is not working in laravel blade template

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I need to show a modal when a particular link is clicked. But, when I am clicking that link, the modal is visible for less than a sec and then gets invisible again. How to make the modal stable?
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/main.css')}}" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('css/angular.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('css/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('css/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{asset('font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<style>
    .search_option{position:fixed; top:75px; right:-185px; height:40px; z-index:10;overflow:hidden; transition:height 1s, right 1s; border-radius:2px; background:rgba(1,1,1,0.6);color:#eee; padding:6px;}
    .search_option:hover{position:fixed; top:75px; right:0px; height:130px;}
    .search_option input,.search_option button,.search_option option,.search_option select{color:#111;}

    .other_option{position:fixed; top:122px; right:-108px; height:40px; z-index:1; overflow:hidden; transition:height 1s, right 1s; border-radius:2px; background:rgba(1,1,1,0.6);color:#eee; padding:6px;}
    .other_option:hover{position:fixed; top:122px; right:0px; height:67px;}
    .other_option button{color:#121;}
    .other_option ul a{color:#ccc;}
    .other_option ul a:hover{color:#fff; text-decoration:none;}
</style>


<body >

@section('header')
    @foreach($user as $data)
<div class="header row" style="margin:0px; height:9vh!important; width:100%; margin-top:-95px; padding-top:3px; margin-left: -0px!important; background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#563D7D, #6E5398); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#563D7D, #6E5398); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#563D7D, #6E5398); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#563D7D, #6E5398);">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="img/jj.png" style="height:4vw; width:4vw; padding:0.5vw; border-radius:2vw;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a href="logout">  <img src="{{$data['users_fb_photo']}}" class="pull-right" style="height:4vw; width:4vw; padding:0.5vw; border-radius:2vw;"></a>
    </div>

</div>
@endforeach
@show

@yield('content')
<div class="search_option">
    <form>
        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>&nbsp<input type="text" placeholder="search"><br><br>
        get posts from last <select>
            <option>1 day</option>
            <option>1 month</option>
            <option>1 year</option>
        </select>or <br><br>
        get posts about <input type="text" placeholder="hashtag value" style="width:110px"><br><br>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="other_option">
    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></button>&nbsp
    <ul style="padding-left:50px; list-style: none; margin-top:-30px;">



        <!--MODAL LINK-->



        <li style="padding:5px;"><b><a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit Profile</a></b></li>
        <li  style="padding:5px;"><b>Log out</b></li></a>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are including jQuery and Bootstrap's core JS file twice.

Remove these scripts in your `<head>` part because it has been included twice, and after that, everything should be working fine.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('css/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: actually, there was only one link. I added that second offline link just a few minute before I asked this question... It doesn't work with one link anyway.

Comment: I see.. but in your blade code above, I can't see `</body> </html>` closing tags, can you verify that?